# Error on TIdHTTP on Setting Host and Port at Runtime for SMS web service delivery

Tags: web-services, delphi, http, indy, delphi-xe3

I am trying to use an SMS API for Delphi from http://www.human.com.br but I get an 'access violation' error when the component tries to set the host and port of the webservice after creating an instance of Indy's `TIdHTTP`.

```
host := TidHTTP.Create; 
host.Socket.Port := 80; // error right here!
host.Socket.Host := 'system.human.com.br';
uri := TidURI.Create();
```

The original component was created in Indy60 and I have Indy170, so the was no `Socket` between `host` and `Port` and I had to put it.

What is wrong? I tried to put the component directly on the form and in the button code I did the Socket settings and I get the same error too!

---

The send method they use is this:

```
 data := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
 host.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
 host.Post(strSMStext , data);
```

Comment: Why are you setting the host or port at all? You can specify the address when you call `Get` or `Post`.

Comment: Assert(Assigned(Host.Socket))

Comment: I did not did that code. It's from human.com.br as said in the question. But thay said they do not give us support for indy10 or delphi-xe3.

Comment: This web service requires login and password

Comment: the complete library and exameple are in: http://www.zenvia.com.br/desenvolvedores/bibliotecas/delphi.zip

Comment: @EASI: The code you have shown is wrong even for earlier versions of Indy. Whoever wrote that code obviously did not understand how to use `TIdHTTP` properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Socket` property is a special property that provides easier access to socket-specific functionality when the current `IOHandler` property value points at a `TIdIOHandlerSocket` descendant component.  It is `nil` otherwise.  You should NOT be setting the `Socket.Host` and `Socket.Port` properties directly.  `TIdTCPClient.Connect()` handles that internally for you.  To set a Host/Port, you need to use the `TIdTCPClient.Host` and `TIdTCPClient.Port` properties instead.  However, `TIdHTTP` is an exception to that rule, because `TIdHTTP` sets the Host/Port properties internally for you based on the URL you pass to it, eg:

```
host := TidHTTP.Create; 
host.Get('http://system.human.com.br/', ...); // <-- sets Host and Port for you!
```

```
host := TidHTTP.Create; 
host.Post('http://system.human.com.br/', ...); // <-- sets Host and Port for you!
```

So DO NOT set the Host/Port properties manually at all.  That has always been true in every Indy version that has a `TIdHTTP` component.

Posting a `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream` object forces the `Content-Type` header to be `multipart/form-data`.  You cannot override that.  Trying to send MIME-encoded data using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is just plain wrong.  If you really want to send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data, you need to post a `TStrings` object instead, eg:

```
data := TStringList.Create;
data.Add('name=value');
...
host.Post(strSMStext , data);
```

When posting a `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` or a `TStrings`, let `TIdHTTP.Post()` decide which `Content-Type` value to use, don't set it manually.

Looking at the library code you provided a link to, the following changes need to be made:

1. Remove the assignment of the `http.Port` and `http.Host` properties from the `TSMSSender` constructor.
2. in `TSMSSender.SimpleSend()`, prepend the desired Host to the URL being created:

   ```
   //StrEnvio := '/GatewayIntegration/msgSms.do?dispatch=send' +
   StrEnvio := 'http://system.human.com.br/GatewayIntegration/msgSms.do?dispatch=send' +
   ```
3. in `TSMSSender.MultipleSend()`, remove the assignment of the `http.Request.ContentType` property.