# TidHTTP error "A port is needed" when trying to Connect

Tags: delphi-7, indy

I am attempting to connect to a secure server using a `TIdHTTP` component. I have assigned a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` I/O Handler to the `IOHandler` property, and I have downloaded the OpenSSL files.

When I invoke `Connect()`, it generates an "A port is required" exception. [Another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966594/) suggests that `Host` and `Port` should be assigned automatically for a `TIdHTTP`. Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

If I don't invoke `Connect()`, the site responds with an error 406, because the connection is not secure.

Relevant bits of code are:

```
try
  IdHttp1.Connect ('https://test-api.service.hmrc.gov.uk');
  IdHttp1.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue ('Accept', 'application/vnd.hmrc.1.0+json');

  result := IdHTTP1.Get('https://test-api.service.hmrc.gov.uk/hello/world');
except
  on E: Exception do
    memo1.lines.add (E.ClassName + ': ' + E.message);
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Port is required" error is because the `Port` property has not been assigned a value yet when `Connect()` is called.

But, the thing is, unlike with other TCP client components, you are NOT supposed to call `Connect()` *directly* at all when using `TIdHTTP`. Its `Get()` method (and other request methods) will handle that internally for you. So, you need to remove the `Connect()` call from your code.

HTTP is a stateless protocol. The underlying TCP connection may be persistent, or it may be disconnected, between multiple requests to the same server. Client and server negotiate that on a per-request basis. `TIdHTTP` handles that detail internally for you, by  parsing URLs for Host and Port information (as I explained in the other post you mentioned) and disconnecting/reconnecting the TCP connection as needed.

All you have to do is provide a valid URL to `Get()` (and others) and let `TIdHTTP` manage the TCP connection for you.

On a separate note, you should not be using the `Request.CustomHeaders` property to set the `Accept` request header. Use the `Request.Accept` property instead.

Try this:

```
IdHttp1.Request.Accept := 'application/vnd.hmrc.1.0+json';
try
  Result := IdHTTP1.Get('https://test-api.service.hmrc.gov.uk/hello/world');
except
  on E: Exception do
    Memo1.Lines.Add(E.ClassName + ': ' + E.message);
end;
```

As for response code 406, the fact that you get any response at all means you have a valid HTTP connection to the server. But 406 DOES NOT mean the connection is unsecure, as you claim (in fact, it can't be, since you are requesting an HTTPS url). 406 actually means the server could not deliver its response data to you in a format that you explicitly requested as being acceptable.  In this case, the response could not be given in the JSON format that you want.

So, you need to figure out why the server is not sending JSON and fix that, or you need to ammend your `Accept` request header to include the format that the server wants to use instead.

My *guess* is the server is probably trying to send back an error message in a non-JSON format (maybe in HTML instead), so try removing your `Accept` request header temporarily so you can look at the actual response, and then update your request code as needed.

Comment: Thank you. Using IdHTTP1.Request.Accept resolved the 406 response. Trying to guess which of the properties or methods to use has not proved easy, when the documentation runs to 4876 pages.